# Stud contact of IC / non IC rated can light (yes, it is both IC and non IC)

Tags: electrical

I'm installing a bunch of pot lights that have all 3 labels on the cans:

- IC rated, max 7W LED GU10
- Type IC max 7W GUI10 LED / Type Non IC max 50W GUI10
- Warning: do not install insulation within 3" of fixture sides or wiring compartment nor above fixture in such a manner to entrap heat.

WTF?

There is no insulation in the ceiling, but one row must touch the joist. Can I use them for that row or not? Technically I'm using 7W LEDs that came with the cans, so they are IC rated.  Then again, nothing stops next guy dumpster diving for 50W halogen GU10 bulbs and using them, making cans non IC rated.

Do I move them 3" from the joist, live with broken symmetry, and learn to match popcorn texture on the ceiling?

Do I swap that row for IC rated cans, or are they going to be twice as wide (and so will break symmetry with other rows anyway?)

Or do I change the row for canless LEDs or same diameter and luminosity?

Will inspection be fine with "technically IC rated at the moment" installation?

This is in Canada if code particulars matter.

**EDIT**:
This is the product: https://nadair.com/recessed/product/recess-3inch/
I have older model (720 vs 735 on site now), but all relevant properties are the same.

I noticed they have "thermal switch", so they will disconnect if they overheat, I guess that solves next guy problem.

Comment: What make/model are said cans?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The next guy is not your responsibility. Cross out the non-IC rating and insulate (if insulation is appropriate here) or just cross out the non-IC rating on the ones next to the joist.

Comment: Agreed, and since non-LED is hard to come by, getting more difficult every year, this is not an issue. Keep/file the box or label that states it's IC rated for LED. (per Electrician in Canada)

Comment: That's what I thought when I was running a new outlet on a kitchen counter, but inspector had a different idea and said I should make it a split outlet like the other ones in the kitchen...